# how to run apcahe2 localhost in nitrous.io Ubuntu Stack

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, localhost, nitrousio

I am running ubuntu stack on nitrous.io cloud platform.
I want to run php files on it and install apache2 server on it also.
But I am unable to run localhost on it;
It giving error of "`port not specified`" when I am taking preview of it, on port 3000.

Please help me out regarding this.

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

```
apache default port is 80
configure port 
change the local host to 0.0.0.0 instead 127.0.0.1
```

This will solve the problem

[image]

[![enter configure the port ][2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI1RN.png)

[image]

Comment: i talking about nitrous.io cloud platform not about local machine.

Comment: my cloud URL is "<name>.nitrousapp.com"

Comment: oh sorry my mistake please check the ports.conf file  @ANSHJAIN

Comment: yes i am getting your point, but can you please tell me the exact path of the .conf file in ubuntu to which are you talking about.

Comment: @ANSHJAIN `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` for port configuration  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: @ANSHJAIN you can add the port in nitrous.io.cloud please the port `80`  which is default port for apache2 server and be sure that changing the `localhost ip-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0`

Comment: but there is no such line in these both files where i can edit localhost ip address

Comment: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` change ip here